# Functional way to get some info from graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks, functional-style

Given some graph I need to gather some info from vertexes and edges.
Here what I have, I think it's rather procedural way.
I'd like to know how to make the same thing but in functional way. Have seen Reap/Sow combo but don't know how to use it here in proper way.
Would appreciate any help.

```
i = 6;
edges = {1 -> 3, 1 -> 5, 2 -> 1, 2 -> 6, 5 -> 2, 5 -> 6, 6 -> 1, 6 -> 4};
graph = Graph[edges, VertexSize -> Medium, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed[{"Name"}, {Center}], 
  GraphLayout ->  "CircularEmbedding"]
ugraph = UndirectedGraph[graph];
parent = Array[0 &, i];
depth = Array[0 &, i];
direction = Array[0 &, i];
dynasty = {};
highlight = {};
rt = {};
edgeHandler[e_] := Module[{from, to},
   from = e[[1]];
   to = e[[2]];
   parent[[to]] = from;
   depth[[to]] = depth[[from]] + 1;
   If[MemberQ[edges, from -> to], 
        direction[[to]] = 1; 
    AppendTo[highlight, from \[DirectedEdge] to], 
        direction[[to]] = -1; AppendTo[highlight, to \[DirectedEdge] from]
    ];
   AppendTo[rt, from \[DirectedEdge] to];
   ];
vertexHandler[v_] := (
   AppendTo[dynasty, v];
   );
depth[[1]] = 0;
direction[[1]] = 0;
parent[[1]] = 0;
DepthFirstScan[ugraph, 
  1, {"FrontierEdge" -> edgeHandler, 
   "PrevisitVertex" -> vertexHandler}];
```

Comment: What information are you trying to extract?

Comment: It's better to also explain in plain English what you are trying to do, in addition to the code.